# Creating custom 2FA provider

Tags: magento2, module, security, plugin

I'd like to enable the 2FA [extension](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/extension-install-two-factor-authentication.html)  but I'd like to write my own provider (e.g. not Authy or Google Authenticator).

Anybody who can point me in the right direction? I have been working with WordPress for several years, but Magento is all new to me.

Comment: You mean in this extension you want to write your custom code?